# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager error in Spring MVC while pulling data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitymanager

I am trying to learn creating ReST API end points using spring mvc and Hibernate without using springboot. When I am running my end point , I am getting internal server error saying that ,

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String, java.lang.Class)" because "this.entityManager" is null`.

My spring-servlet.xml file under src/main/webapp/web-1nf is like the following,

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/company" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="postgresql" />
    <!--<property name="socketTimeout" value="10"/>-->

    <beans:property name="connectionProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="socketTimeout">10</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
 <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
 <beans:list>
 <beans:value>com.springmvc.Employee</beans:value>
</beans:list>
</beans:property>

<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
 <beans:props>
   <beans:prop 
     key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   </beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
 </beans:props>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc" />


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionMgr"/>

 <beans:bean id="transactionMgr" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="mgrFactory"/>
 </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="mgrFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springmvc"/>
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
   </beans:property>
   <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
      <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
   </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

My controller is ,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mvchibernate")
public class CompanyController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

 @GetMapping(value = "/getAllEmployees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeesList() {
     
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Employee> listOfEmployees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        return listOfEmployees;
    }
}
```

And my service class like the following,

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

@Autowired
EmployeeDAO employeeDaoObj;

public List getAllEmployees() { 
    return employeeDaoObj.getAllEmployees();
  }
}
```

And DAO implementation ,

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAO {

@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    
    String jpql = "SELECT e FROM Employee e";
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, Employee.class);
    
       return query.getResultList();
    
        }
}
```

Here in my DAO class I autowired the entitymanager.And while running I am getting `Cannot invoke javax.persistence.EntityManager` and last showing that `because "this.entityManager" is null`.

So can anyone guide me to resolve this issue or kindly refer any documentation to follow please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18846709/6572971 might be helpful

Comment: Can you confirm if all defined `jpaProperties` are currently accessible & these are not getting set as `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit from my previous answer, After reviewing your code below is what you are currently doing:

1. You created `PersistenceConfig.java` with `Configuration` annotation. This class is empty & it looks you have commented it after creating & defining beans.
2. Spring is actually checking  `PersistenceConfig.java` for finding configurations instead of going to your xml.
3. Move your xml config to `src/main/resources`  & for supporting best practice rename it to `persistence.xml`.
4. Now, you have to tell spring to read your configs from `persistence.xml` instead of looking anywhere else. Comment out `Configuration` annotation from `PersistenceConfig.java` & use below annotation in your main class :

:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "classpath:persistence.xml" })
public class SpringMvcHibernateRestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcHibernateRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

5. Also, I suggest to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of
   `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` as it will be inline with your latest spring & jpa versions.
   Once you used this, you will be able to see entitymanager got created properly.

Edit : As per OP's comment, point number 5 is not required on their machine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It listing rest of all. But entitymanager bean is not getting listing in console.

Comment: @Mr.DevEng, can you share what versions of spring, jpa you are using in project?

Comment: spring 5.3 and data jpa 2.7

Comment: ok, your `component` scan has `com.springmvc` & your `packagesToScan` in `MgrFactory` is `com.restDemo` . can you please confirm if package struct is correct? I was thinking if your `packagesToScan`  would be `com.springmvc.restDemo` ?

Comment: No its com.springmvc only. That mistake already corrected in xml early and I forgot to update here.

Comment: ok, is it possible for you to mock your project & upload it somewhere like in  git? as this error seems too specific to me. If its not possible, that is fine, no problem on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246743/discussion-between-mr-deveng-and-ashish-patil).

Comment: hi,  I waited for some time in chat room, but need to go now, please can you share any further observations offline if you can so that I can check on that. thanks

Comment: i shared as a study project zip file. Please look on when you gets time. link - https://github.com/princevarghesev/springhibernatestudy

Comment: @Mr.DevEng , I have just updated my answer, this is working fine on my local machine. Please verify now

Comment: @Mr.DevEng, I just updated comment about point 5 as per your confirmation. Strangely I never got duplicate beans error about mgrFactory otherwise would have suggested that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the `transactionManager` bean here:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

But the bean is actually named `transactionMgr`:

```xml
 <beans:bean id="transactionMgr" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="MgrFactory"/>
 </beans:bean>
```

You should reference the correct name:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionMgr"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I modified the naming mismatch and updated in my question. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there are two options:

1. define [PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) bean - it is responsible for injecting `@PersistenceContext` fields (though documentation says it should be registered automatically, m.b. it is worth to debug it to understand the reason):

```xml
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

2. define EntityManager factory bean and use `@Autowired` instead of `@PersistenceContext`:

```xml
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="mgrFactory"/>
</bean>
```